# How to create custom delegate in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have created delegate method and working in Xcode lower version but not working in Xcode 6.1.

Its showing error **Cannot Find protocol declaration NSObject**

Tried code:
**.h file**

```
@class ReportCell;
@protocol keyboardDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (BOOL)leaveKeyboard:(ReportCell *)cell ;

@end


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ReportCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgReport;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtReport;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewReport;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <keyboardDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

**.m file**

```
 #import "ReportCell.h"

    @implementation ReportCell

    - (void)awakeFromNib
    {
        // Initialization code
    }

    - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {

        [_delegate leaveKeyboard:self];
        [self.superview endEditing:YES];
        [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hey You can solve you problem by following change in your .h file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ReportCell;
@protocol keyboardDelegate;

@interface ReportCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgReport;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtReport;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewReport;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <keyboardDelegate> delegate;
@end

@protocol keyboardDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (BOOL)leaveKeyboard:(ReportCell *)cell ;
@end
```

Comment: -Excellant answer It is realy helpful for us thanks!